# Are questions asking "What are the media queries for <insert device name here>?" on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I saw a question asking about media queries for the new iPhones come up recently, and I couldn't imagine that this would be on-topic. So I voted to close as a request for an external resource (since I imagine Apple publishes the specifications of their devices somewhere).

However, I did a search for similar questions and found quite a few:

- [iPhone 5 CSS media query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12539697)
- [CSS media queries for Iphone 7 and 7 plus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42528836)
- [iPhone X / 8 / 8 Plus CSS media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46313640)
- [iPhone X vs iPad media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51249422)
- [Correct Media Query for IPad Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41978487)
- [3 media queries for iphone portrait, landscape and ipad portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13910255)
- [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6370690)
- [Common CSS Media Queries Break Points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16443380)
- [Which are the most important media queries to use in creating mobile responsive design?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12045893)
- [What Are The Best Width Ranges for Media Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13637106)
- [What is the media query for large desktops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42415141)
- [And many hundreds (or thousands?) more...](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+media+query+for+device)

So it appears that these are, if not on topic, then at least popular. Of course, getting other people to do research for you is always going to be popular...

This is not to say any question asking for media queries is necessarily bad. I found the answer to the following incredibly broad question edifying:

[How to code CSS media queries targeting ALL mobile devices and tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12469875)

If they are okay, perhaps we should consider a more specific tag than [media-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-queries), like [media-query-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-query-request) or [device-media-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-media-queries). That would at least make it easier for those of us who are interested [media-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-queries), but not interested in searching for device resolutions, to ignore them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Media queries aren't off-site resources. They are code.

These questions aren't off-topic. They're just based on the very poor, and frankly false, premise that media queries were somehow intended to be device-specific rather than specific to features or form factors (which is why vendors don't really maintain such lists as you allude to). And they are *extremely* prolifically duplicated for some reason.

But that doesn't make these questions any less answerable or less on-topic for the site. Maybe somebody *does* have a use case that necessitates writing a media query targeting devices that share a common but highly specific display size (a *de facto* "standard" display size, if you will), and they happen to know of a reference device such as the iPhone that has that display form factor. That's not at all a request for an off-site resource. That's a question seeking a solution to a web development problem.

If a question were asking for a link to a resource that aggregates all the media queries for a variety of devices, *that* would be off-topic.

I wonder if a [device-media-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-media-queries) tag would be useful for categorization, though... as much of a false premise I can call it, it's a fact of life that that's how a lot of developers think of media queries.

Comment: Well, pretty much all requests for an off-site resource are also seeking a solution to a development problem; "where can I find a library that foos by bars?" is trying to solve the problem of fooing bars. What I meant was that the specifics for any given device are an external resource that can be found.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: True, I really don't know how to describe "not a request for an off-site resource" without just saying "not a request for an off-site resource". But I would hope that you understand what I mean and are not about to dismiss my argument on the basis of semantics.

Comment: Yeah, I do understand. It's just the recent question about Stack Overflow becoming a debugging service led me to think that we're also a code-writing service, and, apparently, a research service. Fair enough; just want to see where the consensus lies.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: It might be the duplicate fatigue setting in - I see so many of these questions myself I can't help but wonder if a resource exists somewhere (and I'm sure there are some out there, actually). But it's so difficult to find a well-answered canonical (if one even exists) with which to hammer incoming duplicates.

Comment: The duplication lies in close similarities in endeavor. The _premise_ is the same, yet answers to one would make positively no sense on another, well, unless you were targeting the exact same device for similar reasons. It's a mess that isn't at all unique to us, but these are real problems people encounter. Certainly isn't the only space where we make up for vendors being, well, vendors.

Comment: @Tim Post: I'm referring to duplicates that ask about the same devices or questions that have lots of overlap. Stuff like "media query for iPhone 5 and below" and "media query for iPhone 5 and 5s", or "media query for iPhone X and iPhone 8" and "media query for iPhone 6, 6s, 7 and 8", or dozens of copies of "media query for iPhone X". Of course, "media query for iPhone X" would not be a duplicate of "media query for iPhone 8" for obvious reasons. This much overlap does necessitate some form of aggregation, though I'm still averse to calling these questions resource requests by nature.

Comment: @HereticMonkey In what sense is it true that *"specifics for any given device are an external resource"* beyond the trivial sense that the "specifics" in question might, conceivably, already be published on external site somewhere?

Comment: @MarkAmery I've already been admonished about that by BoltClock. I don't feel like rehashing the argument.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I guess I don't grasp what your perspective was to begin with, because I don't see any sense in which these questions can be characterised as resource requests that wouldn't be equally applicable to literally every question ever asked; the limited existing conversation between you and Boltclock didn't make that perspective any clearer to me.

Comment: That tag would likely be akin to [tag:nullpointerexception].